# my website is stopped after server reboot

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

Everytime I reboot, the website is listed as Stopped in IIS. I have to rightclick, my default website, then click Start. This used to not happen. It used to start up when I reboot. Does anyone know what causes this to happen?

It shows error  like this **Login failed to open database**

Comment: Well - first thing to check. Does the database credentials still work? Is the database located on the correct database server? Also; when you say reboot do you mean reboot of the machine and is the database server located on the same machine? Because your IIS site might be starting up before your database (although I would expect a different error message). But well - first things first - check the credentials.

Comment: yes credentials is right whenever server is rebooted then this problem occur

Comment: And is the SQL server started? Is the Database attached in it? And can you - after say 5 minutes  - start up the site again manually in IIS?

Comment: no sql server our main server(window server).yes database are in the same server

Comment: On the pool, you have set to stop if many errors occurs in a  small amount of time, thats why your site is stopped - you also need to find the reason of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do the Following things it will resolve your issue:

1. Open services

   1. Set IIS Admin Services Startup type to Automatic (Delay Start) instead of Automatic
   2. Set Worldwide Web Services Startup type to Automatic (Delay Start) instead of Automatic